# TypeScript does not infer type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following function:

```js
type DefaultEntity = {
  id: string;
  createdBy: string;
  [fieldName: string]: unknown;
};

abstract find<T, Schema extends string | (new () => T)>(
    schema: Schema,
    id: string,
): Promise<(Schema extends string ? DefaultEntity : T) | null>;
```

When I call it with a string as `schema` the return type is `DefaultEntity`. However if I use `MyClass` for the schema argument the return type is `unknown` not `MyClass`. It should be `MyClass` because `T` becomes `MyClass`. Did I miss something or is this something TypeScript just cannot do?

Comment: Can you show how are you calling it. A TS playground would be preferrable

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue you're having, instead of just describing it in words.  (to prev commenter: such code should at minimum be included directly in the question; a TS playground link is a nice supplement but it would not suffice by itself)

Comment: Here is a minimal reproducible example. What is the best why to share it? The TS Playground link was way to long. https://codesandbox.io/s/xr3g2j?file=/index.ts

Comment: Please [edit] it into the question as plaintext.  External IDE links are great but they do not suffice.  I would copy it for you, but it's a legal gray area: nobody but you has clear copyright permissions to copy it to here.  Once it's here the SO terms of use allow others to copy it from there.

Comment: @Ruudy You can use [tsplay.dev](https://tsplay.dev) to shorten that link (although adding the code directly to the question is still a must).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To infer the type of Schema you don't need an additional `T` type parameter. You just have to infer the instance-type of the class either by using the `infer T` keyword or using the built in helper `InstanceType<Class>`. Like this:

```
type DefaultEntity = {
  id: string;
  createdBy: string;
  [fieldName: string]: unknown;
};

abstract class Base {
    // The first way
    abstract find<Schema extends string | (new () => any)>(
        schema: Schema,
        id: string,
    ): Promise<(Schema extends (new () => infer T) ? T : DefaultEntity) | null>;

    // this also works
    abstract find2<Schema extends string | (new () => any)>(
        schema: Schema,
        id: string,
    ): Promise<(Schema extends (new () => any) ? InstanceType<Schema> : DefaultEntity) | null>;
}

class UserEntity {
    id: string = ''
    createdBy: string = ''
    name: string = ''
}

class BaseImpl extends Base {
    async a () {
        (await this.find('asdfqer' , 'asdfasd')) satisfies DefaultEntity | null;
        (await this.find(UserEntity, 'asdf') ) satisfies UserEntity | null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** it's better to use overloads or even separate methods, i.e `findByName(string, string)` and `findByEntity(Schema, string)`, it would be much easier to maintain and read in the future.

Comment: Thanks, this approach is what I was looking for. I agree with out that separate methods would be better to maintain, however I am building a library and I think the approach with a single method better for DX. Or do you have a different opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Use overloads

```
find<T, Schema extends string>(
    schema: Schema,
    id: string,
): Promise<DefaultEntity | null>;
find<T, Schema extends (new () => T)>(
    schema: Schema,
    id: string,
): Promise<T | null>;
find<T, Schema extends string | (new () => T)>(
    schema: Schema,
    id: string,
): Promise<DefaultEntity | T | null>;
```